# NVD3 - Using JSON url data with LinePlusBarChart (mapping values)

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm trying to use the NVD3 library to make graphs but I can't get a JSON url to work properly with the code.

Graph script:

```
d3.json("jsondata3.json",function(error,data){
var chart;
nv.addGraph(function() {
chart = nv.models.linePlusBarChart()
  .x(function(d) { return d.label })
  .y(function(d) { return d.value })
  .margin({top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 175})

 chart.y1Axis.tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));
     chart.y2Axis.tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));

  d3.select('#chart svg')
  .datum(data)
  .transition().duration(500)
  .call(chart);

 nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

 chart.dispatch.on('stateChange', function(e) { nv.log('New State:', JSON.stringify(e)); });

 return chart;
 });
 });
```

JSON data format:

```
[{"TRANSACTION_DAY":"20130620","MT_ATTEMPTED":4505891,"MT_SUCCESS":83.54,"MO_ATTEMPTED":321857,"MO_SUCCESS":98.9},{"TRANSACTION_DAY":"20130621","MT_ATTEMPTED":6636631,"MT_SUCCESS":81.33,"MO_ATTEMPTED":311954,"MO_SUCCESS":98.66},{"TRANSACTION_DAY":"20130622","MT_ATTEMPTED":2708897,"MT_SUCCESS":90.47,"MO_ATTEMPTED":334279,"MO_SUCCESS":98.95} ]
```

The example came with this code (which works obviously) but I recognize it has slightly different formatting from my JSON data. Also a "map.series.values" function was used there.

```
var testdata = [
  {
    "key" : "Quantity" ,
    "bar": true,
    "values" : [ [ 1327986000000 , 690033.0] , [ 1330491600000 , 690033.0] , [ 1333166400000 , 514733.0] , [ 1335758400000 , 514733.0]]
  },
  {
    "key" : "Price" ,
    "values" : [ [ 1322629200000 , 382.2] , [ 1325307600000 , 405.0] , [ 1327986000000 , 456.48] , [ 1330491600000 , 542.44] , [ 1333166400000 , 599.55] , [ 1335758400000 , 583.98] ]
  }
].map(function(series) {
  series.values = series.values.map(function(d) { return {x: d[0], y: d[1] } });
  return series;
});
```

So how do I get my JSON file to work properly with this code? I'm lost...

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Yes. I got the error: "d.values is undefined"

Comment: You would need to at least change the accessors for `x` and `y`, i.e. return `d.TRANSACTION_DAY` and `d.MT_SUCCESS` or whatever is appropriate.

Comment: OK, I did that. I still get "d.values is undefined."

Comment: Well, it looks like you'll have to reformat your JSON to the structure of the JSON in the example.

Comment: I do understand that. The only problem is that the JSON I have to use in my charts is auto-generated by an API and that format is used elsewhere, so it can't be changed there. What I was hoping is that there would be some code I could add to my script as a workaround to formatting the JSON structure.

Comment: Here is a helpful link I found where the guy who created NVD3 talks about JSON urls but I still can't get it working... https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/d3-js/rt-tjxFVlfs/UJaJ_CO8ggEJ

Comment: Ok, so you'll need to write a function that takes your JSON and transforms it into the structure that's required.

Comment: Yes I agree. Do you have any pointers on that? The function 

`[{#,#}].map(function(series) {
         series.values = series.values.map(function(d) { return {x: d[0], y: d[1] } });
          return series;
        }); 
`
is really confusing me. I can't get it to work with a JSONurl. I tried:

`var jsonURL = "jsondata4.json"

.map(function(series) {
         series.values = series.values.map(function(d) { return {x: d[0], y: d[1] } });
          return series;
        }); 
`
And it returns ""jsondata4.json".map is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

I think you still need to format your json data exactly same as the format of the sample data. Try this.

Notice: javascript timestamp is in millisecond so you should convert your timestamp (20130620 etc.) to unix timestamp and multiple 1000.

```
 var testdata = [
  {
    "key" : "MT_ATTEMPTED" ,
    "bar": true,
    "values" : [ [ 4505891 , 20130620] , [ 6636631 , 20130621] , [ 2708897 , 20130622] ]
  },
  {
    "key" : "MT_SUCCESS" ,
    "values" : [ [ 83.54 , 20130620] , [ 81.33 , 20130621] , [ 90.47 , 20130622] ]
  },
  {
    "key" : "MO_ATTEMPTED" ,
    "values" : [ [ 321857 , 20130620] , [ 311954 , 20130621] , [ 334279 , 20130622] ]
  },
  {
    "key" : "MO_SUCCESS" ,
    "values" : [ [ 98.9 , 20130620] , [ 98.66 , 20130621] , [ 98.95 , 20130622] ]
  },
].map(function(series) {
  series.values = series.values.map(function(d) { return {x: d[0], y: d[1] } });
  return series;
});
```